# Cannot convert value type "User?" to expected argument type "User!"

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-authentication

I just upgraded the pod file on my Xcode project for Firebase and it displayed a bunch of errors. When signing up a user I get the error `Cannot convert value type "User?" to expected argument type "User!"`

I'm not sure what the problem is. I tried changing some of the optional values to get it working, but I do not seem to understand well what the issue is.

Here's the function where I have the error:

*The code has been modified with the solution to my issue*

```
import Firebase
// Sign Up Function
func signUp(username: String, name: String, email: String, password: String){

    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (user, error) in
        if error == nil {
            self.setUserInfo(user: user, username: username, name: name, email: email, password: password)

        }
        else{
            print(error?.localizedDescription as Any)
        }
    })

}

// Set the user info to Firebase storage. username, and password
private func setUserInfo(user: Firebase.User!, username: String, name: String, email: String, password: String){

       if error == nil {
           self.saveUserInfo(user: user, username: username, name: name, password: password)
       }
       else{
           print(error?.localizedDescription as Any)
       }
}
```

**EDIT:**
As user ryanwils mentioned, wherever I use `FIRUser`needed to be replaced with `Firebase.User`

Here's a link to the Migration guide that explained this a little bit further: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/naming-migration-guide

*Note that the code has been updated so no errors are given as of the day of this edit*

Comment: Try this:
self.setUserInfo(user: user!, username: username, name: name, email: email, password: password)

Comment: @Bruno Recillas your user object is not optional.Try changing to user?

Comment: @OMK I tried it before and still the same error /:

Comment: @TusharSharma When I do that, it tells me `Optional chain has no effect, expression already produces "User?"`

Comment: What if you do not provide any type just give user.

Comment: @BrunoRecillas try giving user object as parameter not class name .

Comment: @TusharSharma it gives me the error `Cannot convert value type “User?” to expected argument type “User”`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150692/discussion-between-tushar-sharma-and-bruno-recillas).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The new Firebase version dropped the `FIR` prefix on most types so now `FIRUser` is called `User`. Do you already have a `User` struct or class in your app? If so, you'll need to change the parameter in the`setUserInfo` call should accept a `Firebase.User` (notice no `!`), not `User!`.

Then, when you're calling it you can either grab it with `if let`, `guard let` or force unwrap it with `user!` as you pass it in.

Let me know if that's not the case and I can try to help further!

Edit: Including a link to the [Firebase 4 Swift Migration Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/naming-migration-guide) that explains all the changes necessary.

Comment: I figured out what you meant. Someone else on reddit sent me the link to https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/naming-migration-guide which explain this a little more. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

You are receiving ***user*** in your completion block given that the **error** received is nil. So basically the type of the **user** retrieved is optional so.

```
private func setUserInfo(user: User?, username: String, name: String, email: String, password: String){
    if error == nil && user != nil
     {
       self.saveUserInfo(user: user!, username: username, name: name, password: password)
      } else {

       print(error?.localizedDescription as Any)
}
```

Comment: Tried that out. It gave me the following: `Cannot convert value type “User?” to expected argument type “User?”`

Comment: I do not understand why it gives the error after your answer. It makes sense to me

Answer (score 1):

In the firebase completion handler the User object is optional but in your method you are expecting the non-optional User object. You can fix it like:

```
// Sign Up Function
func signUp(username: String, name: String, email: String, password: String
{
    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (user, error) in
        if error == nil && user != nil
        {
            // error happens here
            self.setUserInfo(user: user!, username: username, name: name, email: email, password: password)

        }
        else
        {
            print(error?.localizedDescription as Any)
        }
    })
}

// Set the user info to Firebase storage. Profile picture change, username, and password
private func setUserInfo(user: User, username: String, name: String, email: String, password: String)
{
    if error == nil
    {
        self.saveUserInfo(user: user, username: username, name: name, password: password)
    }
    else
    {
        print(error?.localizedDescription as Any)
    }
}
```

Comment: When I add the `!` it returns the following: `Cannot convert value type “User” to expected argument type “User!”`

Comment: @BrunoRecillas: Can you check with the updated code ?

Comment: I get the following: `Cannot convert value type “User?” to expected argument type “User” `

Comment: @BrunoRecillas: In which line you are getting the error ? Same line ? Are you using the above code which I've added ?

Comment: yes the same line. The error is the following `Cannot convert value type “User” to expected argument type “User”`